# Aggregate rows with conditions, sum quantitative values, and keep character values of the max

Tags: r, aggregate, tidyverse, r-sf

I have a sf object of points within same polygons.
I want to aggregate all info by polygon Id and keep only one point per polygon : summing quantitative values and keeping character values of the max population with a fcode starting with "P".

I don't know how I can do that.

Here, an exemple with a sample of my sf (6 points in one polygon)

```r
#My sf with 6 points in the same polygon (Poly.id =1), so I want to aggregate by Poly.id
str(Paris)
Classes ‘sf’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ geonameId             : chr  "2988507" "9844895" "2988623" "9843563" ...
 $ asciiName             : chr  "Paris" "Paris 01 Ancien - Quartier Champs-Elysees" "Paris 05 Pantheon" "Paris 09 Ancien - Quartier Hotel-de-Ville" ...
 $ members_etmun         : num  30 0 0 0 0 0
 $ members_urbact        : num  3 0 0 0 0 0
 $ participations_eucicop: num  175 1 9 13 1 6
 $ partners_eucicop      : num  151 1 7 8 1 4
 $ projects_eucicop      : num  156 1 8 13 1 6
 $ fcodeName             : chr  "capital of a political entity" "historical populated place" "populated place" "historical populated place" ...
 $ fcode                 : chr  "PPLC" "PPLH" "PPL" "PPLH" ...
 $ countryCode           : chr  "FR" "FR" "FR" "FR" ...
 $ continentCode         : chr  "EU" "EU" "EU" "EU" ...
 $ population            : chr  "2138551" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ CityId                : int  2 3 4 5 6 7
 $ Poly.id               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ geometry              :sfc_POINT of length 6; first list element:  'XY' num  3760488 2889158
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "geonameId" "asciiName" "members_etmun" "members_urbact" ...
```

Here, the output I want (Get all character variables of the first row, because it's the max of "population" and the fcode starts with "P", then sum variables(3:7)).
So something like that :

```r
str(Paris)
Classes ‘sf’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ geonameId             : chr  "2988507" 
 $ asciiName             : chr  "Paris"
 $ members_etmun         : num  30 
 $ members_urbact        : num  3 
 $ participations_eucicop: num  205
 $ partners_eucicop      : num  172
 $ projects_eucicop      : num  185
 $ fcodeName             : chr  "capital of a political entity" 
 $ fcode                 : chr  "PPLC" 
 $ countryCode           : chr  "FR" 
 $ continentCode         : chr  "EU" 
 $ population            : chr  "2138551" 
 $ CityId                : int  2 
 $ Poly.id               : int  1 
 $ geometry              :sfc_POINT of length 1; first list element:  'XY' num  3760488 2889158
  ...
```

I've tried several things with dplyr or the function aggregate but I don't know how to implement conditions (sum of some quantitative variables, and conditional selection of qualitative values)

Below : the info for the reprex

```r
  Paris <-
    structure(
      list(
        geonameId = c(
          "2988507",
          "9844895",
          "2988623",
          "9843563",
          "9843589",
          "2970479"
        ),
        asciiName = c(
          "Paris",
          "Paris 01 Ancien - Quartier Champs-Elysees",
          "Paris 05 Pantheon",
          "Paris 09 Ancien - Quartier Hotel-de-Ville",
          "Paris 10 Ancien - Quartier Invalides",
          "Paris 15 Vaugirard"
        ),
        members_etmun = c(30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        members_urbact = c(3,
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        participations_eucicop = c(175, 1, 9, 13,
                                   1, 6),
        partners_eucicop = c(151, 1, 7, 8, 1, 4),
        projects_eucicop = c(156,
                             1, 8, 13, 1, 6),
        fcodeName = c(
          "capital of a political entity",
          "historical populated place",
          "populated place",
          "historical populated place",
          "historical populated place",
          "populated place"
        ),
        fcode = c("PPLC",
                  "PPLH", "PPL", "PPLH", "PPLH", "PPL"),
        countryCode = c("FR",
                        "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR"),
        continentCode = c("EU", "EU",
                          "EU", "EU", "EU", "EU"),
        population = c("2138551", "0", "0",
                       "0", "0", "0"),
        CityId = 2:7,
        Poly.id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                    1L, 1L),
        geometry = structure(
          list(
            structure(
              c(3760487.79387524,
                2889157.59339236),
              class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
            ),
            structure(
              c(3757309.96074126,
                2891227.55260787),
              class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
            ),
            structure(
              c(3760266.48357105,
                2888217.53980758),
              class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
            ),
            structure(
              c(3760964.29140438,
                2889376.36175204),
              class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
            ),
            structure(
              c(3757255.00710537,
                2889909.86397746),
              class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
            ),
            structure(
              c(3756810.81051837,
                2888176.61058656),
              class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
            )
          ),
          class = c("sfc_POINT",
                    "sfc"),
          precision = 0,
          bbox = structure(
            c(
              xmin = 3756810.81051837,
              ymin = 2888176.61058656,
              xmax = 3760964.29140438,
              ymax = 2891227.55260787
            ),
            class = "bbox"
          ),
          crs = structure(
            list(epsg = 3035L, proj4string = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"),
            class = "crs"
          ),
          n_empty = 0L
        )
      ),
      row.names = c(NA,
                    6L),
      sf_column = "geometry",
      agr = structure(
        c(
          geonameId = NA_integer_,
          asciiName = NA_integer_,
          members_etmun = NA_integer_,
          members_urbact = NA_integer_,
          participations_eucicop = NA_integer_,
          partners_eucicop = NA_integer_,
          projects_eucicop = NA_integer_,
          fcodeName = NA_integer_,
          fcode = NA_integer_,
          countryCode = NA_integer_,
          continentCode = NA_integer_,
          population = NA_integer_,
          CityId = NA_integer_,
          Poly.id = NA_integer_
        ),
        class = "factor",
        .Label = c("constant",
                   "aggregate", "identity")
      ),
      class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
    )
```

What kind of function do I have to use in order to do something like this ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't really understand what your goal is (maybe add an desired output data frame?), but you can add conditions in dplyr within ````mutate````: ````mutate( new_column = case_when(condition ~ operation))````.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an easier way to do this but...

You could use `by` to create the row of the dataframe for each polygon id, then `rbind` to bind them back together into a single dataframe.

I don't fully understand your 'keeping character values of the max population with an fcode starting with p' but you can adapt the code below if I haven't quite got it right:

```
## First change the population to a numeric:
Paris$population <- as.numeric(Paris$population)

# This will apply the function in FUN to each subset of d defined by a unique poly.id
polygons <- by(data=Paris, INDICES = list(Paris$Poly.id) , FUN = function(d){

  # Identify all the rows with fcode that starts with P
  startswithP <- d[substr(d$fcode,1,1)=="P",]

  # Now get the row with the highest population from those rows
  # There might be more than one of these so just take the first row.
  maxpop <- startswithP[startswithP$population == max(startswithP$population),][1,]

  # Now construct the row of my dataframe.
  # First sum all the numeric rows of d.
  # Then identify all the character rows of maxpop
  data.frame( as.list(apply(d[sapply(d, is.numeric)],2,sum)), 
              maxpop[sapply(maxpop, is.character)])
})

# Now I have a list of one-row dataframes I can rbind them together.
Paris.perpolygon <- do.call(rbind, polygons)                
Paris.perpolygon
```

Comment: Thank you for this precise and helpful answer. Your old answer works fine (because I don't want to sum "population"). I tried the edited version of your solution but I ended up with an error like 
"Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'type' (list) de l'argument incorrect
Called from: apply(d[sapply(d, is.numeric)], 2, sum)"

Comment: No problem.  My new answer works fine on your small example so it must be something in your full dataset that I can't see.